# Access "global" mocha.js functions when using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, mocha.js

I am including Mocha.js with the excellent [use shim](https://github.com/tbranyen/use.js) for a Require.js-based site.

How do I access the define() and it() BDD functions declared by Mocha when using Require.js?

Here is a basic code example:

test.js:

```
var mocha    = require('use!mocha')
  , testFile = require('testFile.js')

mocha.setup('bdd');
mocha.run();
```

testFile.js:

```
define(function(require) {
  // describe() and it() are not available
  describe('Book', function() {
    it('should have pages', function() {

    });
  });
});
```

I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: describe is not defined` when running in the browser.

I have tried window.describe and tried moving the require('testFile.js') to after the mocha.setup('bdd'). I know I am missing something. Probably passing the context to mocha somehow.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that the global functions such as `describe` and `it` are set up by `mocha.setup()`. You can use shim config's `init` property to call `mocha.setup()` before mocha is exported.

```
requirejs.config({
  shim: {
    'mocha': {
      init: function () {
        this.mocha.setup('bdd');
        return this.mocha;
      }
    }
  }
});

require(['mocha', 'test/some_test'], function (mocha) {
  mocha.run();
});
```

Test files need to require mocha.

```
define(['mocha'], function (mocha) {    
  describe('Something', function () {
    // ...
  });
});
```

Shim config's `init` property was introduced in [RequireJS 2.1](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.1#wiki-breaking-shim). You might be able to use `exports` property instead of `init` with [RequireJS 2.0](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-shim).

Comment: Alas for Node users: 'Error: Shim config not supported in Node'

Comment: this worked for me (requirejs+configfile+testem+mocha)

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution in geddski's [amd-testing examples](https://github.com/geddski/amd-testing/blob/master/mocha/runner.html) project.

Instead of including the test file(s) at the top along with mocha like so:

```
define(['use!mocha', 'testFile'],
function(Mocha, TestFile) {
  mocha.setup('bdd');
  mocha.run();
});
```

The test file(s) should be included as another require call and mocha.run() embedded in the callback:

```
define(['use!mocha'],
function(Mocha) {
  mocha.setup('bdd');

  // Include the test files here and call mocha.run() after.
  require(['testFile'],
  function(TestFile) {
    mocha.run();
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, you'll want to pass the done param in it() and call done() in your test cases. Otherwise your test may throw an error but mocha will claim it passed.

Comment: Yuck!  Is this still the best solution?

Comment: Ethan - I hope there's a better solution. Please post another answer if you do find one!

Comment: My solution was to not setup Mocha / Chai as dependencies in my RequireJS build. It ends up being too convoluted, and for what in the end?  I still use RequireJS to build all my tests into a single script (and manage test only dependencies), but I assume now that I've loaded app, Mocha, Chai, then tests.  You can either pass these as arguments to a runner like Testacular, or use a test runner HTML page with the script tags manually ordered.  I feel this is a good compromise solution.

Comment: Note that I also always findNestedDependencies, and I don't load scripts from CDNs or with the 'async' style requires... so this solution may or may not work for you depending on your particular situation.

Comment: New link is https://github.com/geddski/amd-testing/blob/master/mocha/runner.html (I cannot enter this edit because it's only 6 characters of change).